# Pasar datos de firebase a un RecyclerView en un Fragment, Kotlin

Tags: firebase, kotlin, firestore

Estoy empezando a programar en Kotlin y tengo un poco de lio, he hecho un proyecto en el que tengo que pasar datos de firebase firestore a un recyclerview en un fragment. Hasta ahí todo bien, el problema es que no consigo que los datos me los pase correctamente, me carga bien el recyclerview y me detecta cuantos documentos hay pero no me carga bien los datos y no se porqué es ya que no me da ningún error.

Este es el codigo del fragment

```
class VoluntarisFragment : Fragment() {
// TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
private var param1: String? = null
private var param2: String? = null
private val database = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
var voluntaris = ArrayList<voluntari>()
lateinit var myAdapter: adapterVoluntari


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    arguments?.let {
        param1 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM1)
        param2 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM2)
    }
}

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_voluntaris, container, false)


    val recyclerView:RecyclerView=view.findViewById(R.id.voluntariReciclador)
    recyclerView.layoutManager=LinearLayoutManager(activity, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false)




    myAdapter = adapterVoluntari(voluntaris)

    recyclerView.adapter=myAdapter

    loadVoluntariData()


    return view
}

 fun loadVoluntariData() {

    database.collection("voluntaris").addSnapshotListener(object : EventListener<QuerySnapshot>{
        override fun onEvent(
            value: QuerySnapshot?,
            error: FirebaseFirestoreException?
        ) {
            if (error != null){

                Log.e("Firestore Error:  ", error.message.toString())
                return
            }

            for (dc : DocumentChange in value?.documentChanges!!){
                if (dc.type == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED){
                    voluntaris.add(dc.document.toObject(voluntari::class.java))

                }
            }
            myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
            Log.d("Documento: ","$voluntaris")

        }
    })

}
```

Este es el codigo de la clase de donde saco los objetos que se cargan en el recyclerview

```
class voluntari(var indicatiu:String ?=null, var dni:String ?=null, var dataincorporacio:String ?=null, var datanaixement:String ?=null, var carrec:String ?=null, var mail:String ?=null, var telefon:String ?=null, var nom:String ?=null, var cognom:String ?=null, var estat:String ?=null) {}
```

Este es el codigo del adapter para el recyclerview

```
class adapterVoluntari(var list: ArrayList<voluntari>): RecyclerView.Adapter<adapterVoluntari.viewHolder>(){

class viewHolder(view:View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view){

    fun bindItems(data: voluntari){
        val indicatiu:TextView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.voluntaritextview)
        val carrec:TextView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.carrecvoluntari)
        val nom:TextView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.nomvoluntaritextview)
        val mail:TextView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.mailvoluntari)
        val telefon:TextView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.telefonvoluntari)
        val estat:TextView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.estatTextview)

        indicatiu.text=data.indicatiu
        carrec.text=data.carrec
        nom.text=data.nom
        mail.text=data.mail
        telefon.text=data.telefon
        estat.text=data.estat

    }
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): viewHolder {
    val v=LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.voluntari_cardview,parent, false)

    return viewHolder(v)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: adapterVoluntari.viewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.bindItems(list[position])
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return list.size
}
```

Y esto es lo que acaba pasando, me detecta que en la base de datos de firebase hay 3 documentos y me crea los 3 cardview en el recyclerview pero no me pasa ningún dato
[image: Resultado de emulador]

Alguien me podría echar un cable? Muchisimas gracias de adelantado!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Que lastima que recién lo veo, ya pasaron 7 meses desde tu publicación, ya lo resolviste? Consejo, todos los problemas relacionados con Android Studio siempre los busco en ingles y por algún motivo siempre encuentro solución.

Comment: Hola FerFury, bienvenido, esta es la zona de respuestas, te sugiero que elimines tu comentario, a fin de evitar recibir votos negativos, se que es frustrante no tener acceso a los comentarios, solo te puedo decir que tengas paciencia, apenas sumes unos puntos, vas a poder acceder a ellos y también al chat. 
Aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!

Comment: Hola Bienvenido, puedes hacer una nueva pregunta, haciendo referencia a esta, es importante agregar el código esencial y que se muestra en el LogCat , revisar [ask], saludos.